Can't build go app on ARM64: gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-m64'
I am building multi-arch docker images with buildx on an ARM64 machine and I have problems compiling the Go code on ARM64 for arm64. However, this does not seem to be a docker issue.
On my local machine with AMD64 the Go code compilation is fine but on the ARM64 there is an error during compilation. Following Dockerfile:
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM golang:1-bookworm

ARG BUILDPLATFORM
ARG TARGETPLATFORM
ARG TARGETOS
ARG TARGETARCH

...

RUN go mod tidy
RUN go mod vendor

ENV CGO_ENABLED=1
ENV GOOS=${TARGETOS}
ENV GOARCH=${TARGETARCH}

...

RUN apt install g++-x86-64-linux-gnu gcc-x86-64-linux-gnu libc6-dev-amd64-cross binutils
...
# Multiple arm cross compilation issues, see:
# https://github.com/golang/go/issues/64715
# https://github.com/golang/go/issues/64190#issuecomment-1813243547
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58244095/gcc-7-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-m64
RUN if [ "$TARGETPLATFORM" = "linux/arm64" ]; then apt install gccgo-arm-linux-gnueabihf binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu -y; fi
RUN if [ "$TARGETPLATFORM" = "linux/arm64" ]; then GOARCH='arm' GOHOSTARCH='arm' CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc GOGCCFLAGS="-march=armv8-a" CXX=arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ go build -gcflags="-l -N" -o ./main; else go build -o ./main; fi

I pretty much tried all workaround and fixes I could find and still the command fails on the build server with:
...
> [linux/arm64->amd64 37/37] RUN if [ "linux/amd64" = "linux/arm64" ]; then GOARCH='arm' GOHOSTARCH='arm' CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc GOGCCFLAGS="-march=armv8-a" CXX=arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ go build -gcflags="-l -N" -o ./main; else go build -o ./main; fi:
3.529 # runtime/cgo
3.529 gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-m64'
...

No matter which combination of parameters I use (or none at all) I get this error. I also used if [ "$TARGETPLATFORM" = "linux/arm64" ] because there seems to be an issue with the GOARCH being set to arm64, which causes another error.
One of the packages which is notorious for making problems is the sqlite3 driver, maybe that could be an issue.
However, I'm running out of ideas. I can't get the image get build on my ARM64 server to get a proper docker build for ARM64.
